# Merge two 2D Numpy array's while persevering row order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the follow 2D numpy arrays with the columns X, and Y

```
[(476301.98163511883, 6178749.129456658)
 (477927.0510582989, 6178741.4760845825)
 (477918.79328165855, 6177112.834659822)]


[(476301.98163511883, 6175045.129456658)
 (477927.0510582989, 6175037.4760845825)
 (477918.79328165855, 6173408.834659822)]
```

I'm trying to merge the two together while preserving line order

Result would look like this:

```
[(476301.98163511883, 6178749.129456658), (476301.98163511883, 6175045.129456658)
 (477927.0510582989, 6178741.4760845825),  (477927.0510582989, 6175037.4760845825)
 (477918.79328165855, 6177112.834659822),  (477918.79328165855, 6173408.834659822)]
```

I currently have it working by using a generator like this but really feel this is **NOT** the right way to do it.

```
    def generator_array():
        for value in both_arrays:
            yield value

    x = generator_array()

    feature_list = []

    try:
        while x:
            pt1 = next(x)
            pt2 = next(x)
            feature_list.append((pt1[0], pt1[1], pt2[0], pt2[1]))
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by doing the following

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn

merged_array = rfn.merge_arrays((array1,array2), usemask = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking because your code doesn't produce the result you say you want, but would:

```
np.hstack((a,b))
```

work, where `a` and `b` are your two arrays?

Comment: `np.hstack((a, b)).reshape(6, 2)` will match their exact output.

Comment: True, that: edited. I think hstack and your concatenate method are basically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

[`concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) would work:

```
a=np.array([(476301.98163511883, 6178749.129456658), (477927.0510582989, 6178741.4760845825), (477918.79328165855, 6177112.834659822)])
b=np.array([(476301.98163511883, 6175045.129456658), (477927.0510582989, 6175037.4760845825), (477918.79328165855, 6173408.834659822)])

np.concatenate((a,b),axis=1)

array([[  476301.98163512,  6178749.12945666,   476301.98163512,
         6175045.12945666],
       [  477927.0510583 ,  6178741.47608458,   477927.0510583 ,
         6175037.47608458],
       [  477918.79328166,  6177112.83465982,   477918.79328166,
         6173408.83465982]])
```

Comment: @atomh331s Note: That my data is not comma separated.Is there an easy way to comma separate the tuples? When I try this code it just append's the second array to the end of the first.

Comment: @user765015 Can you post your numpy arrays as they are actually formatted, ideally so we can cut 'n' paste?

Comment: @atomh331s I did I think, it's the first part of my code. I know it's a Structured Array (Record Array) where the first element is "X", and the second is "Y". I know I can access a particluat column by going north_array['Y'] += distance Could this be why it's not working for me?